# How can I UPDATE fields separately with Prisma?

Tags: javascript, next.js, crud, prisma

I have an object called `Post` with fields that I need to be able to UPDATE separately. For example, the object will have three fields: `title` `content` `summary`.

**Use case**

I can create a post object and save it in my DB by filling in the field `title`, and the other fields with empty strings. The idea is to be able to go to the individual post page via it's id, and then update the other fields as and when i need to.

On my **page** I have this code to update the title `only`:

```js
    const updateTitleData = async () => {
            try {
                await fetch(`/api/story/${id}`, {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: JSON.stringify(title)
                })
                refreshData()
            } catch (error) {
                toast.error('Document could not be updated')
                console.error(error);
            }
        };
```

In my **API** route, I have the following:

```js
    const storyId = req.query.id
    const {title, content, summary} = req.body
     else if (req.method !== 'PUT') {
            console.log("Note could not be modified")
            res.status(400).json({message: "Note could not be modified"})
        } else {
           await prisma.story.update({
                where: {id: storyId},
                data: {
                    title,
                    content,
                    summary
                }
            })
            res.status(200).json({message: ' updated'})
        }
```

I can't get this to work, no mutation happens when I have it this way, **i.e**

```
const {title, content, summary} = req.body
```

But when I have it this way

```
const title = req.body
const content = req.body
const summary = req.body
```

If I update just one of these, I get a mutation, **but** it updates all the 3 fields with the same value.

How can I just update one field at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `title` is a string. If you are passing

```
body: JSON.stringify(title)
```

in the API then `req.body` will be a string. And when you are doing

```
const title = req.body
const content = req.body
const summary = req.body
```

then this string will be stored in all three variables. And you thus all three attributes of the post will be updated with the same value.

Typically you would pass something like:

```
body: {
  title: "new title"
}
```

in the API.

Then the body would be that object. And if you do

```
const {title, content, summary} = req.body
```

`title` will be the string `new title`, `content` and `summary` will be `undefined`.

You can then use these values to update your database accordingly.